# How to calculate near and far plane for glOrtho in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am using orthographic projection glOrtho for my scene. I implemented a virtual trackball to rotate an object beside that I also implemented a zoom in/out on the view matrix. Say I have a cube of size 100 unit and is located at the position of (0,-40000,0) far from the origin. If the center of rotation is located at the origin once the user rotate the cube and after zoom in or out, it could be position at some where (0,0,2500000) (this position is just an assumption and it is calculated after multiplied by the view matrix). Currently I define a very big range of near(-150000) and far(150000) plane, but some time the object still lie outside either the near or far plane and the object just turn invisible, if I define a larger near and far clipping plane say -1000000 and 1000000, it will produce an ungly z artifacts. So my question is how do I correctly calculate the near and far plane when user rotate the object in real time? Thanks in advance!

Update:
I have implemented a bounding sphere for the cube. I use the inverse of view matrix to calculate the camera position and calculate the distance of the camera position from the center of the bounding sphere (the center of the bounding sphere is transformed by the view matrix). But I couldn't get it to work. can you further explain what is the relationship between the camera position and the near plane?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using the "bounding sphere". If you know the data bounding box, the maximum diagonal length is the diameter of the bounding sphere.

Let's say you calculate the distance 'dCC' from the camera position to the center of the sphere. Let 'r' the radius of that sphere. Then:

```
Near = dCC - r - smallMargin
Far = dCC + r + smallMargin
```

'smallMargin' is a value used just to avoid clipping points on the surface of the sphere due to numerical precision issues.

The center of the sphere should be the center of rotation. If not, the diameter should grow so as to cover all data.

Comment: Ya, I have implemented a bounding sphere for the cube. I use the inverse of view matrix to calculate the camera position and calculate the distance of the camera position from the center of the bounding sphere (the center of the bounding sphere is transformed by the view matrix). But I couldn't get it to work. can you further explain what is the relationship between the camera position and the near plane?

Comment: 'Near' and 'far' are distances from the camera. Anything closer than 'near' or further than 'far' is clipped, not shown. You can calculate these distances in any coordinate system, View or World spaces. Use the one you have more at hand.